# Populate textboxes when clicking on a row in the DataGridView in VB?

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. I'm having a profiling system for my project and I can now add from VB to SQL using the `DataGridView`.

What I want to do now is **to edit the selected row, when I click the `DataGridView` and it will populate the textbox.** How can I do this?

Comment: try using dgv cellmouseclick event ...

Comment: Hi matzone thanks for the reply. But can you give me an example how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle the `CellClick` event. When you click on the cell of a DataGridView, it will trigger this event.

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
  'Check if the user clicks on a valid row. ie: Not on the row header or column header
  If e.ColumnIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
    'Set the textbox text to the specified column's value
    Textbox1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value '1st column
    Textbox2.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value '2nd column

    'Set the textbox3 text to the cell value the user just clicked on
    Textbox3.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value
  End If
End Sub
```

Keep in mind that `DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0)` will be the first column in your DataGridView (even if it is visible or not).

Comment: Hey alex! Thank you so much for the reply! Im very gracious for the code you gave me! But can I ask a question? What does the If condition do, if I can just do it without it?

Comment: @Fiendcoder Yes you could do without it. Basically this condition checks if you are clicking on DataGridView cells, ignoring Column Header clicks (where `e.ColumnIndex = -1` ) and Row Header clicks (where `e.RowIndex = -1`). Glad I could help.

Comment: Hey thats a cool tweak! Thank you sir! Hoping that you could answer more of my question :)